# Microsoft Azure platform not showing keys

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have subscribed to Microsoft Translator API, and I had the keys shown everything was fine.

Now when I try to view my API Key it keeps crashing and shows following error

> KeysPropertiesPart MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD

Someone help on how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Open a support ticket with them about this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this internally as we have seen a couple reports, but for short term mitigation you can get your keys using Powershell **Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountKey**

```
PS C:\Users\me> Login-AzureRmAccount

Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : email@address.com
TenantId              : xxxxx-86f1-41af-91ab-xxxxxx
SubscriptionId        : xxxxx-3dae-4b96-ad95-xxxxx
SubscriptionName      : subscription
CurrentStorageAccount :


PS C:\Users\me> Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountKey -ResourceGroupName MyCognitiveRG -Name TranslatorAPI

Key1                             Key2
----                             ----
33c7d5ff13f54c30b771e472b8a0a44d b8c627e37460410629b9b3d9908bc72b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows (disabled) free trial. If you sign up for the free subscription you'll be able to get your key. Check out the how to here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html

Comment: Look on the right column. KeysPropertiesPart is the index for some frontend framework to display the keys, but it never does.